# How do I split a string by special characters, but without removing them?

Tags: java, regex

How do I split a string like `(int,x)` into `[(, int, , x, )]`

Comment: You mean like `str.split("");`? This will split on every character

Comment: you need to add more explanation to your question & illustrate by an example by taking a sample input & expected output.

Comment: You are confused in asking what you wanna ask :)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving the problem, define what you mean exactly by special characters (is `_` also a special character for example) and tell what should happen if there are multiple of these special characters next to each other, e.g. `(int,,x)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your expected output, you can use `\b` to split your string and get the expected output,

Here is the Java code,

```
String s = "(int,x)";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\b")));
```

Prints,

```
[(, int, ,, x, )]
```

Comment: i think python is not in the Tags ;)

Comment: @KhalidShah: Changed the code to Java and Java is my main language :) I got so used to python here as comparatively people using Python are more than Java now :) But more happy to post a code in my mother language :)

Comment: upvoted - took me 20 lines of code to do this without regex :(

Comment: @Kartik: Thanks for upvote and exactly this is where regex helps :)